# Why HoA has parenthesis while printing the result

Tags: perl

I have written a script, which do a file parsing and print the data in the screen.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use Data::Dumper;
use List::Util qw /uniq/;


while (my $line = <DATA>){
    chomp $line;
    next if $line =~ /^#/;
    if ($line =~ m/^\s*Node :\s*(.*?)\s*$/) { 
        $node = $1;
    } elsif ($line =~ m/^\s*DeviceReference :\s*(.*)\s*$/) { 
        $Hash1{$node} = [ split /, /,$1 ] ; 
    } elsif ($line =~ m/^\s*AntRef :\s*(.*)\s*$/) { 
        $Hash2{$node} = [ split /, /,$1 ] ; 
    } 
}

foreach my $Sec (keys %Hash1){
    ($until_sec = $Sec) =~ s/,Car=\d+//;
    if (exists $Hash2{$until_sec}){
        foreach my $Group (@{$Hash1{$Sec}}){
            $Group =~ s/\[|\]//;
            $Group =~ s/,DeviceSet=\d+,Device=\d+//;
            push @{$Final{$Group}}, @{$Hash2{$until_sec}};
        }
    }
}   

foreach my $Group (sort keys %Final){
    ++$i;
    print  "-Group_$i=$Group\n";
    print  "-Ant_$i=", join('###', uniq @{$Final{$Group}}), "\n";
}

__DATA__
Node : Network=12,Node=1,Sec=1,Car=1
DeviceReference : [Network=12,Equ=1,Rack=1,Slot=3,Unit=R-1,Group=R,DeviceSet=1,Device=1, Network=12,Equ=1,Rack=1,Slot=3,Unit=R-1,Group=R,DeviceSet=1,Device=2]

Node : Network=12,Node=1,Sec=1
AntRef : [Network=12,Equ=1,Ant=1-1]
```

**Current Result:**

```
-Group_1=Network=12,Equ=1,Rack=1,Slot=3,Unit=R-1,Group=R
-Ant_1=[Network=12,Equ=1,Ant=1-1]
```

**Expected Result:**

```
-Group_1=Network=12,Equ=1,Rack=1,Slot=3,Unit=R-1,Group=R
-Ant_1=Network=12,Equ=1,Ant=1-1
```

Question: Why there is a square brackets (`[..]`) in the `-Ant_1` value filed? Am I doing something wrong while `push`ing the data into HoA?

Comment: The `[`...`]` are in your input as well? So why shouldn't they make it into the output?

Comment: @Robert I require the data only which are inside `[..]`.

Comment: You're printing the value captured by `m/^\s*DeviceReference :\s*(.*)\s*$/`. Why wouldn't it have square brackets?

Comment: @ikegami You're correct. `m/^\s*AntRef :\s*\[*(.*?)\]*\s*$/` doesn't require `substitution` again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You remove the `[]` from the Group, but not from the values of `%Hash2`.

To remove the square brackets, you can use

```
push @{ $Final{$Group} }, map s/[\]\[]//gr, @{ $Hash2{$until_sec} };
```

Perl 5.14+ is needed for the `/r` modifier. In older versions, use

```
push @{ $Final{$Group} },
    map { (my $x = $_) =~ s/[\]\[]//g; $x }
    @{ $Hash2{$until_sec} };
```

Comment: Thanks @choroba. that solves the problem :)

Answer (score 3):

The square brackets are already in your input data. Unless you remove them, they get carried to the output.

You could change the last `elif` in the first loop to this to remove any square brackets:

```
    } elsif ($line =~ m/^\s*AntRef :\s*(.*)\s*$/) {
        my $ant = $1;
        $ant =~ s/[\[\]]//g;
        $Hash2{$node} = [ split /, /, $ant ] ;
    }
```

Not sure if this is what you want, or if you'd rather remove them only in first and last positions:

```
    } elsif ($line =~ m/^\s*AntRef :\s*(.*)\s*$/) {
        my $ant = $1;
        $ant =~ s/^\[//;
        $ant =~ s/\]$//;
        $Hash2{$node} = [ split /, /, $ant ] ;
    }
```